# How to pass only one parameter from an array of objects as combobox items?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Combobox is pretty simple:

```js
<template>
   <v-combobox
   clearable
   v-model="values"
   :items="items"
   ></v-combobox>
</template>

<script>
data () {
    return {
        items: [
            {"id": 2, "name": "tree"},
            {"id": 4, "name": "grass"},
            {"id": 5, "name": "freeze"},
            {"id": 9, "name": "moss"}
        ],
        values: ''
    }
}
</script>
```

What I want to achieve, is to pass just the `name`s as combo-box items.

Entries like `:items="items.name"` or `:items="c.name in items"` don't work; leaving it as it is makes `[object Object]`s displayed.

Besides displaying just the `name`s, is it possible to preserve the complete object (`name` and `id`) in `values` model on item selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/#api) you should use the `item-text`, `item-value`, and `return-object` props for v-combobox, like this:

```html
<v-combobox
  clearable
  v-model="values"
  ::items="items"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="id"
  return-object
></v-combobox>
```

The `item-text` prop is the name of the property to display in the combobox. `item-value` is the property of the object to use as the value. `return-object` indicates that a selection should return the object it represents, instead of its value (`item-value`).

The `return-object` prop is `true` by default, so you can exclude it if you'd like. The default for `item-value` is `value` and `item-text` is `text`. So if your items had properties `value` and `text` instead of `id` and `name`, it would work as expected without having to specify those props.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the parameters the component receive at the component API section.
For you case, you need to add **item-text**, and **item-value** into your combo-box

```
<v-combobox
   clearable
   v-model="values"
   :items="items"
   item-text="name"
   item-value="id"
></v-combobox>
```